Digits in base-$r$ from modular residue number system
Suppose I have a large integer of the form
$$
N = (a_0 + b_0 r + c_0 r^2)(a_1r^4 + b_1 r^8 + c_1 r^{16})(a_2 r^{32} + b_2 r^{64} + c_2 r^{128}) \cdots (a_{n-1} r^{2^k} + b_{n-1} r^{2^{k+1}} + c_{n-1} r^{2^{k+2}})
$$
Assume $r > \max(a_0, a_1, \cdots a_{n-1}, b_0, b_1, \cdots, b_{n-1}, c_0, c_1, \cdots, c_{n-1})^n$.
Let $M = \{p_i : p_i \in \mathbb{P}\}$ and $\prod p_i > N$.
Say we only have the modular residues $N \bmod p_i$ and $M$.
Question: Is there a way we can compute the digits of the base-$r$ representation of $N$ without applying Chinese Remainder Theorem. For e.g., $a_0 a_1 \cdots a_{n-1}$ would be a digit of $N$ in base-$r$.
My motivation for this is to incrementally compute the digits of the base-$r$ representation and avoid explicitly calculating large exponentiation (ie., large powers of $r$ explicitly).
